# Why node app crashes when req.files is null?

Tags: node.js

I have a frontend app(react) where the user can edit the product like price, description, delete images and add images.
**The problem** occurs when the user **does not want to add new images.**

Then on the backend(nodejs) req.files.newImages as I named it is null
and the backend crashes.

When I **add one image or more everything works as it should because req.files.newImages has a value.**

How to cover the case when the user does not want to add new images and prevent the app from crashing

I use express-fileupload and I use axios and put method to send data.

```
routes.put("/edit-product", (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.files.newImages) // - result app crashed
}
```

Error in console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newImages' of null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if there are any files like this:

```js
if (req.files) {
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively you can use *optional chaining*:

```js
console.log(req.files?.newImages); // will log "undefined"
```

Comment: Thank you,
I persistently checked req.files.newImages

Answer (score 0):

first check if it comes with `console.log(req.files)` with another name, if not, make sure you send it as "multipart" on the front-end side